# Estimate for probability for $\log n - 2\log \log n$ consecutive heads

Tags: probability, estimation

Consider a sequence of $n\geq 1000$ coin flips. Prove that the probability that there isn't a subsequence of $\lfloor \log n - 2\log\log n - 1 \rfloor$ consecutive heads is at most $\frac{1}{n}$.

I am aware that there are general recursions for probabilities of this kind but I am trying to find a slick way to do the above, with or without such recursions, as in the pedestrian way I get stuck into calculations.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: For a loose analysis that I think is good enough, split the $n$ trials into $\geq n/\log_2n$ disjoint, consecutive blocks of length $\log_2 n- 2\log_2\log_2 n-1$. Note that these are independent. What's the probability that a fixed block has all heads? Then what's the probability none of them do?

Comment: Hm I tried that and it kinda didn't work, let me try again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elaborating on my comment:

The probability that a fixed run of length $\lfloor\log n-2\log\log n-1\rfloor$ is all heads is 
\begin{equation}
2^{-(\lfloor \log n-2\log\log n-1\rfloor)}\geq \frac{\log^2 n}{n}.
\end{equation}

Splitting the run of $n$ trials into at least $n/\log n$ disjoint blocks of that length (which can be done as each block has length $<\log n$), clearly the probability none of these blocks are all heads is an upper bound for your event. This probability by independence is at most
\begin{equation}
\bigg(1-\frac{\log^2 n}{n}\bigg)^{n/\log n}\leq 2^{-\log n}=\frac{1}{n}.
\end{equation}
The inequality is $1-x\leq 2^{-x}$, valid for $x\geq 0$.

Comment: A nice answer !

Comment: This is a great answer! I preferred the hint version in the comments, since it left more mystery and room for me to work out details, but it's very hard to deny the elegance and brevity of this answer.

Comment: @AaronMontgomery I absolutely agree. I only wrote it out because the OP indicated they had tried it but didn't succeed, which suggested to me that they had the right idea but made some annoying computational mistake. As I do that myself all the time, I figured writing it out would spare the OP some pain without depriving him/her the chance of coming up with the idea!

Comment: Agreed. I made a few of those silly mistakes myself when I was resolving your hint to an answer -- it's easy to do!